# Replace values in matrix C#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I have the following C# code :

```
int[,] mt = { { 5, 4, 6, 2 }, { 8, 1, 5, 4 }, { 2, 3, 8, 6 }, { 9, 6, 1, 8 } };
        int i, min, index, j, v;
        for (i = 0; i < mt.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            index = 0;
            min = int.MaxValue;
            for (j = 0; j < mt.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                v = mt[j, i];
                if (v < min)
                { min = mt[j, i]; index = j; }
            }
            mt[i, index] = mt[i, i]; mt[i, i] = min;

        }
        for (i = 0; i < mt.GetLength(0); i++)
        {//print the matrix after changes
            for (j = 0; j < mt.GetLength(1); j++)
                Console.Write("{0,3}", mt[i, j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

What this code should do is to replace the minimal value in each col with value that in the same col wich part of the main diagonal (This is quadratic matrix).

So the cell with the minmial value in the col gets the value of the  cell in the main diagonal in the same col, and the cell in the main diagonal gets the value of the cell with the minimal number in the same col.

I tried the code above, but I get this result :

```
{ { 2, 4, 5, 2 }, { 4, 1, 3, 6 }, { 5, 5, 1, 1 }, { 2, 4, 8, 2 } };
```

And this what I should get:

```
   { { 2, 4, 6, 8 }, { 8, 1, 5, 4 }, { 2, 3, 1, 8 }, { 8, 6, 1, 2 } };
```

My question is what should I change in the code to get the idial result?

Wish for help, Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have written:

```
mt[index, i] = mt[i, i];
```

instead of:

```
mt[i, index] = mt[i, i];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you so much, I did so stupid mistake! Thanks again!